# autoscale by part of the dataset

Tags: gnuplot

Is there any way to perform autoscale in gnuplot by only the part of the data in the datafile?
Reading help, I found, that its possible to use "writeback" option of yrange, plot part of the data, then restore yrange and replot. However, this code does not work:

```
set yrange [*:*] writeback
f = "datafile.csv"
plot f u 1:2
set yrange restore
replot f u 1:3
```

It plots only first graph(using data 1:2) and does not plot 1:3 data by replot.

Comment: I do not understand what you are after. I think your script should do exactly what I think you want. Could you include your `datafile.csv` and comment again on what you think is wrong and how it is supposed to look?

Answer (score 1):

The commands above show no terminal/output settings.  I heard [the PNG terminal has issues](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/mailman/message/30408516/), so it might be useful to reset it, and define terminal and output after range restore.  For example:

```
set terminal 'unknown'
set yrange [] writeback
f = "datafile.csv"
plot f u 1:2
set yrange restore
set terminal 'png'
replot f u 1:3
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you maybe looking for something like this:

```
plot f u 1:($2*0.1), f u 1:($3*2)
```

Or what are you referring to with auto scale?

Comment: I have two columns in a file. Say first column has values in range [90..100], second column has values in range [0..100]. I want gnuplot to set yrange by 1st column(90..100 in this example) and draw both plots in this range. If I set autoscale gnuplot select range as [0..100]

Comment: @Nick Try this `set xrange [90:100]` for the x-axis and `set yrange [90:100]` for the y-axis.

Comment: but this does not solve the problem. I do not know range prior drawing. I need to determine it by values in the file